# Adding IList<KeyValuePair<long, string>> to another

Tags: c#, list, collections, append

I am looking to add a list to another list.
'Assessments2' to be appended to 'Assessments1'
I'm aware of 'AddRange()' that does not work in my case.

Here is the code:

```
private IList<KeyValuePair<long, string>> Assessments1 = new List<KeyValuePair<long, string>>();

//Here i'm first adding 'Select All' at the beginning of my list then appending another list returned by DB calls

Assessments1.Add(new KeyValuePair<long, string>(0, ResAppConst.GetText("SelectAll")));
var Assessments2 = GetAssessmentsFromDB().ToList();

//Need to append Assessments2 to Assessments1
```

Comment: `var allAssessments = Assessments1.Concat(Assessments2).ToList()`?

Comment: AddRange is used to add more than one item to a list.  Assessments1 contains one KeyValuePair and you want to add a second  KeyValuePair to Assessments1.